# How to change the text color continuously in android using TextView...?

Tags: android

I want to change the color of a text after every few seconds. I tried generating a random number and using it for setting the color of the text view object in a loop. But the app is not responding. Can anybody help me with this please?

Answer (score 3):

Try running the color-cycling part of your code in a separate thread. For example

```
Thread thread = new Thread( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            int number = // generate random number ;

            runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    TextView text = // get your TextView ;
                    text.setTextColor(number);
                {
            {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
}

thread.start();
```

You will need to run the code that actually changes the TextView via the `runOnUiThread` because Android does not allow other threads to modify parts of an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Handler with .postDelayed() and set it up to have a recursive structure, so each time through it will change the color and then post the next runnable to fire off a few seconds later.